# How Does Windows Handle Non-Realtime USB Audio Sources?

Tags: windows, audio, usb

I am currently researching the feasibility of making a device that outputs PCM audio through the USB audio class streaming interface. This device has its own clock, and importantly does not generate samples at a multiple of 1 hz as the USB spec can specify, and produces packets in asynchronous mode. How does Windows handle it when a USB audio stream is consistently giving it samples at a rate above or below what the USB descriptor indicates, and at what level of the OS is this handled?

Second (and depending on the answer to the first question this may be already answered), the entire purpose of this project would be to capture this digital audio in its native format and sampling rate. What application Windows APIs would provide the exact PCM input from the USB audio stream, with no interpolation or other alterations or artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

IDK about Windows in specific here, but Java on Windows would likely be set up to read the data as an [AudioInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html) and would output as a [SourceDataLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html).

As far as timing issues, PCM processed by the SourceDataLine will be configured to a given sample rate and byte structure (configuration details provided in an AudioFormat class). The code underlying a SourceDataLine employs a buffer and a I think some sort of [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) or the native code implementation of something similar. I'm not entirely clear on this latter detail.

But the gist is that the SourceDataLine will suspend operation until it is able to fulfill its task. Thus, if the native code's DAC function is not ready, the SourceDataLine thread will suspend and wait until the output stage is ready to accept the next block of data for processing.

There are multiple transmission layers on the incoming data, much of which I don't know enough about. But I presume that if you have a way of assembling the incoming packets into a stream (with whatever buffering is required), then you should be able to receive and play PCM. Surely there are structures in C that would provide the equivalent functions of the Java classes I cited.